# Selenium Webdriver Nightwatch.js

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying to click on the 'Customer Login' button. But it does not.

```
module.exports = {
    tags: ['Registration'],
    'Test Registration Page' : function (client) {
         client 
         .url('http://www.globalsqa.com/angularJs-protractor/BankingProject/#/login') // Go to a url
         .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000) // wait till page loads
         .useXpath()
         .click('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button')


       }
 };
```

Comment: Try to use `.pause(5000)` to define if it cannot be found because the page wasn't loaded completly

Comment: Now, it is working. Thanks for your support

Comment: I'm happy that it is working now. Could you please mark my answer as a right one? I'll add now all the information.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.click('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button')
```

with

```
.click('//html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button')
```

`xPath` expression sample `//path/to/element`

EDIT:

Other possibility can be using a CSS selector could be like this one:

```
div.borderM.box.padT20 div.center:first-child button.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg
```

in your case it will be:

```
useCss().click('div.borderM.box.padT20 div.center:first-child button.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg')
```

Also you have to make sure, that your page is loaded properly. For example by using `.pause()`

Comment: Yes, you can check it too.

Comment: ERROR: Unable to locate element: "//html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button" using: xpath

Comment: try CSS selector ´div.center:nth-child(1) > button´

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can try CSS Selector instaed of xPath

Comment: try this xPath `//button[@ng-click='customer()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your current code block you can try the following code block with relative *xpath* as follows :

```
.click("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'][@ng-click=\"customer()\"]")
# or
.click("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' and contains(.,'Customer Login')]")
```

---

### Update (from the comments)

The *XPath* being correct, instead of waiting till page loads, you can `waitForElementVisible('xpath_of_element', 1000)` and then invoke `click()` directly.

Comment: @kunalbhaskar Check the updated code and let me know the status please

Comment: Now syntax is fine, but still it does not able to click on the Customer Login button

Comment: Instead of _waiting till page loads_, can you  `waitForElementVisible('xpath_of_element', 1000)` and then invoke `click()` directly?

Comment: I use .pause(5000). Now, it's working. Thanks for your support